# Qiskit: 'no counts for experiment'

Tags: qiskit

Although I imported `plot_histogram`, I am not getting the output as expected. Here is my code:

````
a = QuantumCircuit(1)
a.z(0)
a.x(0)
a.h(0)
a.sdg(0)
a.t(0)
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = execute(a, backend).result()
counts = result.get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts)
print(c)```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing measurements.

```
a.z(0)
a.x(0)
a.h(0)
a.sdg(0)
a.t(0)
a.measure_all(). #<--
...
```

This will measure the qubits and set a classical register with the result.

Comment: Ya, measurement!! that is a minor thing i couldnt get. Thank you.